# Publish package: 1 checked-in file is ignored by a `.gitignore`

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to publish a new package, this is the content of the `pubspeck.yaml`. It's a pretty simple package, with some helpers functions basically, but i'm getting this error and I have no idea why. I'm using macos.

You can also see the full code here: https://github.com/marcobraghim/suitup

```yaml
name: suitup
description: A bunch of features and stuff to help me create awesome apps
version: 1.0.1
repository: https://github.com/marcobraghim/suitup

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.19.2 <3.0.0'
  flutter: ">=1.17.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_easyloading: ^3.0.5
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  google_fonts: ^4.0.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
```

When I run `flutter pub publish --dry-run` I get the following error message. And NO, I do not have a thing ignoring it at all.

It is already published on https://pub.dev/packages/suitup but the error persists

```
* 1 checked-in file is ignored by a `.gitignore`.
  Previous versions of Pub would include those in the published package.
  
  Consider adjusting your `.gitignore` files to not ignore those files, and if you do not wish to
  publish these files use `.pubignore`. See also dart.dev/go/pubignore
  
  Files that are checked in while gitignored:
  
  linux/flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/path_provider_linux
```

Ps.: Flutter version

```
Flutter 3.7.7 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 2ad6cd72c0 (2 weeks ago) • 2023-03-08 09:41:59 -0800
Engine • revision 1837b5be5f
Tools • Dart 2.19.4 • DevTools 2.20.1
```

Answer (score -1):

this problem is caused by the git repository being out of date.
"linux/flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/path_provider_linux" this file path exists in the github repository but not in the package

Comment: What are you talking about? I don't understand what you meant, this file exists inside my project and if I try to remove it the result is even worst...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).